# How to create user/group associations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I am working on a webapp in PHP/MySQL and I have come to the point where I need to create a user/group association.

Here is what I am shooting for:

- I am going to have an ever growing number of groups and users.
- The users are going to be able to modify their group associations
  whenever they want.
- The group association is going to dictate the priority of content
  displayed on the site.
- Email updates sent to user will be determined by their current group 
  associations.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this user/group association?

My current table structure looks like this (Simplified for ease of communication):

```
Users:
User_ID, User_name, Fname, Lname, is_dealer

Deals:
Deal_ID, Dealer_ID, Deal_name, Deal_content

Dealers:
Dealer_ID, User_ID, Dealer_name, Dealer address.. etc.
```

My initial thoughts are to create a Groups table with Group_ID, and Group_name columns. Then I could do one of two things:

I could create a column in the Groups table called "User_ID" and for every group association I have a row that states the Group_ID, the Group_name, and the User_ID. That option feels like it would create a huge super redundant database table.

The other option I could think of would be to create a Group_ID column in the Users table and just fill it with all of the groups a user is associated with in some sort of array of text that would have to be parsed. The issue here is that I want there to be an unlimited number of groups, and jamming all of a user's group associations into one "value" for each row in my user table seems super sloppy.

Really this is a SQL database logic/design question. 
Any assistance would be a great help.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want we could migrate this question over to our DBA sister site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ . If this is favourable then flag for a mod to migrate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just make a table that relates users to groups. Two columns: one storing the unique user_id and the other one storing the unique group_id.

You do not need a unique key in this table, if you make the user_id-group_id combination unique. Two colums are enough.

```
+---------+      +------------+
| user    |      | user2group |     +----------+
+---------+      +------------+     | group    |
| user_id |----->| user_id    |     +----------+
| name    |      | group_id   |<----| group_id |
| pass    |      +------------+     | name     | 
| ...     |                         | ...      |
+---------+                         +----------+
```

If I remeber correctly, this is one of the three steps of *normalization*. Maybe you shuld have a look at this to.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! Seems obvious now that you say it but for some reason I couldn't figure that out. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AbuDun So does the `group` table actually exist? The `group_id` in the `user2group` table could also refer to the `user_id` in the `user` table?

Comment: @timpeterson this is how you create a many-to-many relationship in a RDBMS like MySQL. `group_id` and `user_id`  in `user2group` are "foreign keys" to their respective tables. Deleting either "parent row" will delete the `user2group` "child row" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a crosstable.

Keep your Users as it is and create following two tables:

```
Groups:
Group_ID, Group_name

Groups_Users:
Group_ID, User_ID
```

This is a typical n:m relationship, without redundant data.

Comment: I agree with you, but he should also use referential integrity for the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

To link the USERS to the GROUPS table in my opinion

You would have to create a third table called  u_g_realationship

Table Structure

```
id    user_id    group_id
--    -------    --------
1     2          7
2     2          5
```

This would make the updating or deleting the relationships very easy compared to jamming it in one column

I hope this solves your problem alex.